# Are the left-chiral and right-chiral yukawa couplings equal?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, fermions, higgs, chirality

I guess another way to ask this is: Does the "physical electron" spend EQUAL time being a left-chiral and right-chiral fermion, on average?

Clarification:
The electron switches between (-1/2 T3, -1Y) and (0 T3, -2Y) components as it interacts with the Higgs vev. Is there a difference in the "lifetime" of the 2 components, or are they exactly equal, or is it unknown?

Update:
I just realized, this might be equivalent to asking if the amplitude to EMIT or ABSORB a higgs is equal, correct? Then by Special Relativity, I assume they must be equal.

Answer (score 2):

The coupling for $f_L \to f_R$ is exactly the same as the one for $f_R \to f_L$ (the Yukawa coupling source of the fermion mass term). So yes, on average a fermion is "as left-handed as right-handed" when propagating freely.